# How to use intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, bundle

I dont understand how to get the intent from other Layout, because I have MenuLayout on wich I have checkboxes for TextSize.

```
if(male_pismo.isChecked()){
        velkost_pisma=22;
         Intent intent_pismo = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
         intent_pismo.putExtra("font_size", velkost_pisma);
         startActivity(intent_pismo);
    }
```

and when I click on checkbox the intent doesnt start. Is there any error in my code? Or I have to use Button to start intent?

And second Question is, I have in my MainActivity code

```
Intent i=getIntent();
    Bundle extras = i.getExtras();
    velkost_pisma=extras.getInt("font_size");
```

and when is nothing in intent my program falls down.

Comment: Add some logs to test whether the code is executed.

Answer (score 0):

> and when I click on checkbox the intent doesnt start.

Did you set [OnCheckedChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener.html) for your CheckBox? You most likely forget to call setOnCheckedChangeLister method for your CheckBox because from snippet of code provided everything looks correct.

> and when is nothing in intent my program falls down.

Here you need to check of Intent data are null or not:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
Bundle extras = i.getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
   velkost_pisma = extras.getInt("font_size");
}
```

Comment: Ok. I add that code to my program. And I dont use OnCheckedChangeListener.

Comment: @Patrick OnCheckedChangeListener is generally recommended for CheckBoxes. Other listeners could work not correctly.

Comment: I added intent test to my code but it still crashes.

//edit SOrry my fault, I forgott delete one line of code after if.

Comment: Yes intent works without crashes but checkboxes nope.

Comment: I solved it by `android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"`

Comment: but tnx to you anyway :)

Comment: @Patrick so if it solved, accept at least answer to be topic completely solved. thanks